# Floyd Rose Question: Should it sit flat with the body of the guitar?

Tags: guitar, tuning

I have a EVH Fender Striped Series guitar with a non-floating floyd rose Bridge. I've had it for about a year now. Recently I looked at it and saw that it was like the bridge was being pulled forwards by the strings and was at an angle. If I de-tune the strings, the bridge goes back flat against the body again.

The strings look straight, but the bridge isn't. Also, it has problems with staying in tune. Like it would get out of tune in less than a minute.

About a month ago I changed the strings, and replaced the old ones with ernie ball strings, and that was my first time doing it. Did I mess something up?

Comment: Were the string gauges like for like?

Comment: As in the same gauges? If so I'm not sure. I can't remember what the originals were, and I had been recommended ernie ball strings from a friend so that's what I got. I do have a feeling that they weren't the same though, they seemed thicker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take the back panel off and tighten the claw screws up equally a turn at a time, tune to pitch and then check its sitting flat now. If not, repeat

your new gauge is pulling harder because they are thicker

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just did this, and while I've only been testing for like 20-25 minutes, it appears to have solved my tuning problems. Rock on!                                                                                          Edit: spelling

Comment: @Paytonium34 can you please accept my answer then?